# Laravel 5.2 syntax for getting a session variable from array

Tags: session, syntax, laravel-5

In my sessions I have added some things OK and can show them OK, however I added the user info as an array

```
session()->put('userinfo',Auth::user());
```

but I cannot seem to recall for display or use on of the userino items, name.

What is the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
{{ session()->get('userinfo')->name }}
```